# iTunes -- making a script for copying album play counts

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm trying to write a script which would let me copy the playcounts of one version of an album to another based on the title of the tracks.

Basically, scenario would be that I have the album on my computer along with all the playcounts. Then I rerip the original CD with higher quality (previously my quality preference was very low).

Now I want to automatically copy the playcounts of my old crappy quality rips to the new high quality ones.

I adopted a script from Doug Adams to try to do this, but when I try to run it it just gives me "A descriptor type mismatch occurred." without any indication as to the line where the problem is.

I've never used Apple Script before; does anybody know where the problem could be?

```
global thismany
tell application "iTunes"
    if selection is not {} then
        set sel to selection
        repeat with t in sel
            set t to contents of t
            if class of t is file track or class of t is URL track then
                if played count of t is 0 then
                    set thismany to 0
                    repeat with t2 in sel
                        set t2 to contents of t2
                        if class of t2 is file track or class of t2 is URL track then
                            if title of t is equal to title of t2 and t2 is not t then
                                set thismany to played count of t2
                                exit repeat
                            end if
                        end if
                    end repeat
                    set played count of t to (thismany as integer)
                    if (thismany as integer) is 0 then
                        try
                            set played date of t to missing value
                        end try
                    end if
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    else -- no track selected
        tell me to message_and_cancel("No tracks selected.")
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, turns out the problem was that there is no such thing as a `title` of a track, the property is called the `name` of the track.

If anybody is interested, the full script can now be found [here](https://github.com/houbysoft/short/blob/master/Copy%20album%20playcounts.scptd.zip).